# Change font size in Scribble document

Tags: fonts, latex, racket, scribble

In latex, I can change the overall font size of my document in the `\documentclass` line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lncs}
\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

How can I change the font size of my document using Scribble?

One possibility is to use `exact` and insert latex code to change the font:

```
(define (exact . items)
  (make-element (make-style "identity" '(exact-chars))
                items))
```

But the problem is that the font is specified on on the `\documentclass` line, which is generated by scribble.

So is there any way to either set the font size from within scribble, or use some latex package to change the font size after the `\documentclass` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the Scribble language and backend you are using. For example, the `scribble/sigplan` language lets you set some font sizes using the language options and targets the PDF backend primarily.

In general, you can override any backend properties like that by using either a style file or a prefix file. A prefix file is probably what you want here, so that you can directly modify the `\documentclass` declaration.

Add something like this to your `prefix.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lncs}
% other stuff here that you need
```

Then supply `--prefix prefix.tex` when you invoke Scribble. You should copy and paste the whole prefix file that comes with the LNCS language if you're using that to avoid losing any preamble commands you need.

If you ever target a non-PDF backend you will need a different prefix file, but it sounds like you are interested in the PDF case primarily.

---

As an aside, if you want to change the font size only locally you can supply the `'smaller` and `'larger` styles on an element. Like `(elem #:style 'smaller "Smaller")`.

Comment: So, if I use a prefix file, it will replace the normal prefix with the one in the file? (Meaning I am responsible for setting the documentclass), yes?

Comment: Yes, that's why you'll have to copy and paste the prefix file from the LNCS package for example. The default Scribble LaTeX prefix file is very minimal though.